# Where can metafont be obtained?

Tags: fonts, metafont, source

Where is the source code or executable for Knuth's `metafont` program? I cannot find it anywhere!

Comment: http://tug.ctan.org/tex-archive/systems/knuth/dist/mf/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The binary should be part of your TeX distribution; its name is `mf`.  The source is available at: [CTAN](http://tug.ctan.org/tex-archive/systems/knuth/dist/mf/)

Answer (score 1):

To be even more specific, it is [here](http://tug.ctan.org/tex-archive/systems/knuth/dist/mf/mf.web), in the file called "mf.web".  It is 23k lines of pascal mixed with heavy documentation that is something like DOXYGEN from the 70's.

If you're running a debian-based distribution the source is also in the "texlive-bin" source package in the "/texk/web2c/mf.web" subdirectory.

Comment: Like TeX, MetaFont is written in WEB. I'm not sure the comaprison with Doxygen really gets the WEB approach across at all!